# Website self-referral

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, google-analytics, analytics

Google Analytics is showing my own root domain is the referral for a large portion of my website's traffic.

So, mywebsite.com is showing as the referrer for www.mywebsite.com.

I have tried adding a referral exclusion within Analytics with no success. I have cleaned my .htaccess which also hasn't been successful

**.htaccess code**

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Redirects mywebsite/uk/anypage to mywebsite.eu/anypage
RewriteRule ^uk/(.*)$ /$1 [NC,R=302,NE,L]

# Redirect 404 to index
ErrorDocument 404 /

# Use www version
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite.eu [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.eu/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

This is what it looks like in Analytics:

[image]

I've put a lot of time into trying to find the cause so any suggestions, .htaccess related or otherwise, are very welcome

Answer (score 0):

Did you migrate recently to Universal Analytics? It migrates the previous utmz cookie values that stored traffic source, so if your users had self-referrals prior to upgrading to UA, this will persist int your data. Could you check if there are new sessions in this traffic?

Comment: We've been on UA and Tag Manager, both with the same result. I recently back-tracked from Tag Manager to UA. A very small percentage (0.67%) of the sessions are new users. Somewhere around 20% of all sessions are self referrals, so it's a big issue

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add to the referral exclusion list your domain with and without the www.

For some reason certain sites it likes to have it while on others it does not, I would definitely try this and then see if the future sessions are any more clean before changing too much with the .htaccess.

Comment: Tried using both non-www and www with no effect